# Overlapping in listview c#

Tags: c#, listview, windows

Good day, I have a list view that looks like this.

[image]

My problem is that the name of the items are overlapping, that name is from the database, do i have to set something in the properties for it not to overlap?

form_load code

```
private void FormAdhocReport_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        LoadReport();
        ToolBar(sRights);
    }
```

LoadReport code:

```
private void LoadReport()
    {
        dsReports.Clear();
        this.listReports.Items.Clear();
        adhoc.AccountRowID = CurrentUserNameRowID;
        string sRetXMLValue = adhoc.get_sp_Reports_View_Owner();
        string XMLDOC = sRetXMLValue;
        ReadXMLData(XMLDOC);
        ListReportData();

        //int count = listReports.Items.Count;
    }
```

ListReportDataCode:

```
private void ListReportData()
    {
        try
        {
            // Get the table from the data set
            DataTable dtable = dsReports.Tables[0];

            // Clear the ListView control
            this.listReports.Items.Clear();

            // Display items in the ListView control
            for (int i = 0; i < dtable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow drow = dtable.Rows[i];
                if (drow.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
                {
                    // Define the list items
                    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(drow["ReportName"].ToString());
                    lvi.ImageIndex = 0;
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["RowID"].ToString());
                    listReports.Items.Add(lvi);
                }
            }
        }
        catch { }

    }
```

Don't mind this codes: `string sRetXMLValue = adhoc.get_sp_Reports_View_Owner();
            string XMLDOC = sRetXMLValue;
            ReadXMLData(XMLDOC);` because they're just for getting the data in the database.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The value displayed doesn't contain any space so the control cannot split the text on more lines. If it is possible you could try to replace the underscore with a space and let the control display the text on more lines. How do you fill the control?

Comment: @Steve I've edited the question. and how can I have space on the value displayed? Someone just passed me this project and I can't quite figure out how he loads this thing. LOL

Comment: `ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(drow["ReportName"].ToString().Replace('_', ' ')); ` Just to try it, if it works I would make it an  answer

Comment: @Steve Nothing happened sir.

Comment: @Steve I've changed the view property into tiles, but the names appear besides the image, not on the bottom of it.